# Font issue in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, fonts

I have some fonts installed on my machine and I use them while creating web pages. Few days back I noticed something, Google chrome was not using my font (Segoe UI Light). Instead, it applied "Times New Roman" on the entire webpage. When I inspected the elements, it shows 'Segoe UI Light' only, but the UI looks something like this (Notice the inspect element window, it still shows Segoe )

[image]

But the user interface on Internet Explorer looks decent (and as expected) :

[image]

Can anybody tell me what the exact problem is. As far as I remember, I have not changed any settings in chrome

**---- EDIT ----**

A simple demo added as per request.

1. HTML

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="x.css">
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>This is some demo text</div>
       <span>This is some demo body. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. CSS

   ```
   div {
       font-family: "segoe ui light";
       font-size: 40px;
   }
   span {
       font-family: "segoe ui light";
       font-size: 20px;
   }
   ```

Comment: Please add your code. It is hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: I had the same problem today. Thought it was "TypeKit".

Comment: @Afsa : It is nothing related to code. A code which was working fine few days back on chrome is not working now. But if you still want, I can post the code.

Comment: @Gagan93 It would be nice if you could add a demo.

Comment: ok sir, I am creating a small demo with just title and some text. I'll add the chrome view and IE view

Comment: @Afsa : added. Sorry for the html part. I cant add html code, it gets rendered like a page

Comment: yes you can add html code, just paste it, then drag and block the code, and press `ctrl + k` to define the `code block`, or you can create the demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post the link here